# Can't download ebook from Amazon to my PC

Tags: amazon, download

Just making this question in case someone encounter the same problem, I will answer it.

So I just bought an ebook for my Kindle in amazon, because some circumstances I have not WIFI available in my house as many other times, therefore I want to dowload it to my PC and transfer it to my Kindle via USB cable, as many other times.

I go to the page where you handle all your ebooks (sorry but I'm not a native english speaker, so I don't know the exact names in english version of amazon web... if you know them, you are officially invited to edit the question :), locate my new ebook, hit the "..." button, select the option to download the ebook and transfer ir via USB and select my kindle in the dropdown menu.

And nothing happens.

Seconds later, suddenly a message appear and dissappear in screen, saying something like "*Download your book from **My multimedia library***" (again, not english native speaker), but the book doesn't get downloaded and I can't for my life find the above mentioned library.

So, I don't have the book, and it seems that the library doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of frustration and searching in internet (seriously, after like 3 hours), suddenly I remember the console. Hit F12 to open Chrome console and what a surprise: an error:

```
Mixed Content: The site at 'https://www.amazon.es/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file
at '**HERE COMES THE DOWNLOAD URL**' was redirected through an insecure connection. 
This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See 
https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.
```

I tried to change chrome settings to no avail, so I just copied the download URL and pasted it in a new tab. It downloaded the book without a problem.

I don't really understand the problem, but yes, just copy/paste the URL and download your ebook.

Comment: Good catch! This is correct behavior by the Browser as it is a security problem by Amazon.

Comment: I see the exact symptoms you do, but only on Firefox.  Tried using Chrome console to get the URL like you suggest... except then the download worked just fine in Chrome.

Comment: @Johan Yes, sometimes it just work fine. I've buyed some books since I wrote this without a problem... well, I suppose they have a bug somewhere and sometimes the download work and sometimes it doesn't :( Anyway, it's good to have a workaround

Answer (score 0):

The process I follow is:

- buy Kindle content on Amazon
- organize content through http://www.amazon.com/myk
- read content on physical kindle e-reader device

providing that the kindle device has internet access it'll sync with what's on the above link.  (I've never "downloaded" a Kindle book per se, so I don't understand your question there.  Of course, the Kindle downloads a book, yes, but that's a fairly automatic process.)

---

not sure I quite understand the question.

Comment: In the question I already said I have no wifi available, so I have to download the book to the pc and then pass it to the kindle via usb.